# Delegate User using EWS by C#

Tags: c#, delegates, exchange-server, impersonation, exchangewebservices

I run this code but it doesn't do anything in my Office 365 Exchange, it didnt get the Inbox or the incoming email to the Impersonated User. And it doesnt give me any errors. Can someone help me this? Or idea why this code is not working with my Office 365 exchange?

```
List<DelegateUser> newAllDelegates = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DelegateUser>();
DelegateUser AllDelegate = new DelegateUser(ImpersonatedEmail);
AllDelegate.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
AllDelegate.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
AllDelegate.Permissions.TasksFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
AllDelegate.Permissions.ContactsFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
AllDelegate.Permissions.NotesFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
AllDelegate.Permissions.JournalFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
newAllDelegates.Add(AllDelegate);
Mailbox mbxPermitted = new Mailbox(_uid);
Collection<DelegateUserResponse> delReturn = service.AddDelegates(mbxPermitted, MeetingRequestsDeliveryScope.DelegatesAndSendInformationToMe, newAllDelegates);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Editor Permission on All to " + ImpersonatedEmail + " On the Mailbox " + _uid + " Added.", "O365 Delegates: Success!");
```

Comment: @drf thank you editing it. Do you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: I can't test currently, but you may need to set `AllDelegate.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevelSpecified = true` (and similar for the other folders, e.g., `InboxFolderPermissionLevelSpecified = true`, etc..

Comment: @drf Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to `Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.DelegateFolderPermissionLevel`

Comment: I believe both CalendarFolderPermissionLevel  and CalendarFolderPermissionLevelSpecified need to be set (same for the other folders), whereas you only set the former. For an example, you may want to refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2011/04/18/setting-rights-permissions-on-folders.aspx.